# Newline characters in HTML tag Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm writing my first project in Google Apps Script to send emails after parsing spreadsheet data. I need to fill `<?=nameList?>` with a list of names, each on it's own line. I build the string with these lines inside a loop:
  
`nameList = nameList.concat(finalName)
nameList = nameList.concat("\r\n")`

The logs show a correctly formatted string:

`[17-08-19 14:59:15:636 PDT] Former member string: a Monster
b Monster
d Monster
f Monster
g Monster`

But in the actual email they appear:
`a Monster b Monster d Monster f Monster g Monster`
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720832/line-break-in-a-message) did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlBody parameter.

```
    MailApp.sendEmail({
         to: "recipient@example.com",
         subject: "Test",
         htmlBody:nameList
})
```

Comment: Let me clarify. `nameList` is one of several parameters that must be filled.  `address = range.getCell(personList[person][0], formerMemberEmailColumn).getDisplayValue()
      var body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('multiple_members_message').evaluate().getContent();

      try{
      //send message
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: address,
          replyTo: replyEmail,
          subject: "Former Members",
          htmlBody: body,
        });`

Comment: Instead of namelist pass the final html string

Comment: How? `var body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('multiple_members_message').evaluate().getAs('string')` errors out.

Comment: `var body = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('multiple_members_message').evaluate().getContent()` ignores the newline characters

Comment: Provide the entire script