# Modify a SendGoogleForm script v2

Tags: powershell, google-apps-script

I am trying to get my SendGoogleForm script to work. The issue I have at the moment is that the message I am sending with the form is including a powershell script, the problem I have is that the send service is breaking the lines in the code which means I have to manually remove all the extra spaces(see example at bottom).

So I thought that there must be a way to print the powershell code to a file instead and attach it to the email that is sent or fix the spaces issue some other way. It would be good if the answers still are displayed as a regular email like they are today but with the powershell code attached somehow.

```
/* Send Google Form by Email v2.1 */
/* For customization, contact the developer at amit@labnol.org */
/* Tutorial: http://www.labnol.org/?p=20884 */

function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

}

function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{  
  try 
  {      
    //Här fyller du i mailadresserna för resp avdelning.
    var it = "test@test.se";

    //Ärende på mailet
    var subject = "testt Ny/redigerad anställning";  

    //Slår ihop alla mailadresser till en.
    var email = hr +","+ security +","+ it;

    //andra variabler
    var bukowskis = "test";
    var temporarypass = "Provide a Temporary Password for this user";
    var semicolon = ";";

    // You may replace this with another email address
    //var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var columns = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var message = "";    

    // Only include form fields that are not blank
    for ( var keys in columns ) {
      var key = columns[keys];
      if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) {
        message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n"; 
      }
      if (key == "Förnamn")
            var fornamn = e.namedValues[key];
        else if (key == "Efternamn")
            var efternamn = e.namedValues[key];
        else if (key == "Placering")
            var placering = e.namedValues[key];
        else if (key == "Titel")
            var titel = e.namedValues[key];
        else if (key == "Avdelning")
            var avdelning = e.namedValues[key];
    }

    //Lägger till eventuellt namn i ämnesraden.
 if(typeof fornamn !== 'undefined'&&typeof efternamn !== 'undefined'){
    subject += ", " + fornamn + " " + efternamn ;
    message +="New-ADUser -SamAccountName '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -Name '"+fornamn+" "+efternamn+"' -GivenName '"+fornamn+"' -Surname '"+efternamn+"' -Description '"+test+", "+avdelning+", "+titel+"' -OfficePhone ' ' -EmailAddress '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"@test.com' -Path 'OU=Users,OU=test,DC=intern,DC=test,DC=se' -Company 'test' -Department '"+avdelning+"' -Title '"+titel+"' "+semicolon+"$NewPassword = (Read-Host -Prompt '"+temporarypass+"' -AsSecureString) "+semicolon+"Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -NewPassword $NewPassword -Reset "+semicolon+"Set-ADAccountControl -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -Enabled $true";
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);     
    }

      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.toString());
      }

}
```

Example of how the output looks today, not able to just copy to Powershell ISE and run it, sadly.

```
New-ADUser -SamAccountName 'gadfgdafg.sdfgsdfg' -Name 'gadfgdafg sdfgsdfg'  
-GivenName 'gadfgdafg' -Surname 'sdfgsdfg' -Description 'Test, Utlämningen, Alternativ 5' -OfficePhone ' '  
-EmailAddress 'gadfgdafg.sdfgsdfg@test.com'  
-Path 'OU=Users,OU=test,DC=intern,DC=test,DC=se'  
-Company 'test' -Department 'Utlämningen' -Title 'Alternativ 5' ;$NewPassword = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Provide a Temporary Password for this user' -AsSecureString) ;Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity 'gadfgdafg.sdfgsdfg' -NewPassword $NewPassword -Reset ;Set-ADAccountControl -Identity 'gadfgdafg.sdfgsdfg' -Enabled $true
```

Thanks in advance, I have tried everything I can think of at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending e-mails, GMail automatically line-wraps your plain-text messages (at around 78 characters per line). In order to avoid this, you can:

1. Use another client other than Gmail. Of course, probably not your preferred option, but something to consider.
2. Get the data through the API. The data you get from it will not be line-wrapped.
3. Send your message as an **HTML** message. You can do that with a small modification of your code:

   - **Before**

   ```
   message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n";
   ...
   subject += ", " + fornamn + " " + efternamn ;
   message +="New-ADUser -SamAccountName '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -Name '"+fornamn+" "+efternamn+"' -GivenName '"+fornamn+"' -Surname '"+efternamn+"' -Description '"+test+", "+avdelning+", "+titel+"' -OfficePhone ' ' -EmailAddress '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"@test.com' -Path 'OU=Users,OU=test,DC=intern,DC=test,DC=se' -Company 'test' -Department '"+avdelning+"' -Title '"+titel+"' "+semicolon+"$NewPassword = (Read-Host -Prompt '"+temporarypass+"' -AsSecureString) "+semicolon+"Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -NewPassword $NewPassword -Reset "+semicolon+"Set-ADAccountControl -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -Enabled $true";
   MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
   ```

   - **After**

   ```
   message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "<br><br>";
   ...
   subject += ", " + fornamn + " " + efternamn ;
   message +="New-ADUser -SamAccountName '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -Name '"+fornamn+" "+efternamn+"' -GivenName '"+fornamn+"' -Surname '"+efternamn+"' -Description '"+test+", "+avdelning+", "+titel+"' -OfficePhone ' ' -EmailAddress '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"@test.com' -Path 'OU=Users,OU=test,DC=intern,DC=test,DC=se' -Company 'test' -Department '"+avdelning+"' -Title '"+titel+"' "+semicolon+"$NewPassword = (Read-Host -Prompt '"+temporarypass+"' -AsSecureString) "+semicolon+"Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -NewPassword $NewPassword -Reset "+semicolon+"Set-ADAccountControl -Identity '"+fornamn+"."+efternamn+"' -Enabled $true";
   var htmlBody = "<html><p>" + message + "</p></html>";
   MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {'htmlBody': htmlBody});
   ```

   The main changes are:

   - Wrapping your text with HTML code, using a paragraph tag.
   - Replacing the newlines inside your "message" for `<br>` tags.

Comment: Hi carlesgg97! Thank you for the answer, it does work but now it has no spaces at all between the lines. The code below will make it easy to read the output, the powershell script is just an extra output which shouldn't have any breaks like it did with your code, but it did it too the whole output.
´´´
 for ( var keys in columns ) {
      var key = columns[keys];
      if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) {
        message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n";
```

Comment: @JohanHård sorry for not realising that there was more text on the email. The idea is that you split your "paragraphs" with <p> tags, so your final message should be created as: `<html><p>first paragraph</p> <p>second paragraph</p> <p>powershell line</p></html>`. You may also be interested in using the [<br> tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp). Let me know if you have any issue with that, Cheers

Comment: I tried making different variables for this and also just to put the whole powershell code in the paragraph. It still removes the line break from the code which outputs the answers.

Comment: @JohanHård I have edited the code, showing just one extra modification you have to do (replacing `\n`'s for `<br>`'s). Let me know if that works for you, cheers!

Comment: carlesgg97 you are a god! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Johan. You're not putting any newline characters into the string, so it's all going to output on a single line. For google-apps-script(js) you can use '/n'. [See examples here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720832/line-break-in-a-message)

Alternatively, to create the powershell file separately and send it as an attachment, you can add the attachment argument to your MailApp function. You'll have to push the output to a file, which will still require '/n' to break up the lines. You'll also have to store the file somewhere that the form has access to. And you'll need to be sure that the recipient email won't flag the .ps1 fine as potentially malicious. (Which it should be doing. Never run scripts from email attachments!) [Attachment example here.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79324/send-email-with-an-attachment-located-in-google-drive)

Have fun!